# Acquiring Identity Claims at startup C# NET6

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I am trying to get the name of the logged in identity user through claims at the very start of the application.

Code in **Program.cs**

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var serviceProvider = app.Services;

using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

var httpContextAccessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
```

results:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

invoking by this line :

```
var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
```

I need this setup for my program. I know it can be done by using the endpoint in the controller and it works for me by using the controller but it's not what I expect.

**In summary**, I need it to return the name of the logged-in IdentityUser at the very start of the program in program.cs.
Who has an idea? (I don't want to use controllers for this)

Additionaly i want to get these claim when my Browser is not open

Comment: _Which_ user do you want to obtain, considering there doesn't have to be any to launch the web server?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [IAuthenticationService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iauthenticationservice?view=aspnetcore-7.0) interface.

```
var authService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>();
var result = await authService.AuthenticateAsync(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

if (result?.Principal != null)
{
    var userName = result.Principal.Identity.Name;
    // Here goes your stuff
}
```

Another way is to implement custom [IStartupFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupfilter?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but i think it will be more complicated than above method.

Comment: result variable return me the same : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. BTW i. added builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)

Comment: Additionaly i want to get these claim when my Browser it not open